# Transceiver Supply isolation with Transformer

Tags: power-supply, isolation, transceiver

I need to supply the Vcc2 for 2 different transceivers, one for the CAN-BUS, like the [ISO1042-Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso1042-q1.pdf) that have a Vcc2 of 5V, and another one (not yet defined) with a Vcc2 of 3.3V.

[image]

On my PCB I have both the 5Vdc and the 3Vdc (used for supplying other ic) and I can't use other dc/dc isolated converter for the Vcc2. I must, therefore, use and isolate the two existing voltages.
For this purpose I think that I can use, for isolating both the voltages, only one power isolation transformer like this from Coilcraft:

[image]

but I'm not sure and I'm a little confused about how I can wiring the transformer for isolating both the voltages.

Referring to the schematic of the transformer, can I wire the 5V at pin 4 and the 3.3V at pin 2 of the transformer with pin 3 and pin 1 connected to their respective digital ground and connect the Vcc2 of the first transceiver at pin 8 and the Vcc2 of the second transceiver at pin 6 (with pin 7 and 5 of the transformer connected to their respective GND)?

Does everything work with the two Vcc2 correctly isolated (even among them) or am I wrong?

The transformer datasheet is [here](https://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/da2303t.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The data sheet tells you how to do it: -

[image]

It uses an [SN6505](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6505a-q1.pdf) transformer driver.

> *can I wire the 5V at pin 4 and the 3.3V at pin 2 of the transformer
>   with pin 3 and pin 1 connected to their respective digital ground and
>   connect the Vcc2 of the first transceiver at pin 8 and the Vcc2 of the
>   second transceiver at pin 6 (with pin 7 and 5 of the transformer
>   connected to their respective GND)?*

No, it's a transformer and it requires an AC voltage drive and a rectifier on the output followed by a regulator to produce Vcc2.

> *and I can't use other dc/dc isolated converter for the Vcc2*

You have to find a way that allows this to happen. You either: -

- use what TI recommends
- find a different CAN bus transceiver that has isolated power transfer built in
- use a DC-to-DC converter such as from Traco etc..